# How to change DocumentRoot to /var/www/public?

Tags: apache2, lamp

I'm new to LAMP and I follow the steps on installing laravel [here](http://www.dev-metal.com/install-laravel-4-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) and it says

```
   Now search for “AllowOverride None” (which should be there TWO times)
   and change both to “AllowOverride All“. Search for these two lines
```

Now I run `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default` then it gives me this

[image]

And then its says **change** this

`DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory /var/www>`

to this

`DocumentRoot /var/www/public
<Directory /var/www/public>`

**Edit:** `ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-available`

[image]
And so I'm stuck on it.
So how can I do that? I'm new to LAMP and laravel.

Comment: did you install apache2 package?

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes  I did sir.

Comment: post the output of `ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-available` in your question. And don't call me sir, just Avinash would be fine.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Question edited. Please check

Comment: @Rinzwind how can I do that? I'm new to `Ubuntu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to copy the backup default file to it's original location and then open it through gedit.

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.save /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Change the line as stated in the question and save the file.